# Logstash email alerts dynamically from multiple log files

Tags: email, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have the logstash config file in which i have written the mail alert for particular text present in the message then automatically send an email with the message. Please find the configuration file (logstash.conf).`

input {

```
file {

  path => [ "\\IP Address\logs/LMS.log.*_bak" ]
  start_position => "beginning"     

 }
```

}

output {

```
elasticsearch {
        bind_host => "127.0.0.1"
        port => "9200"
        protocol => http
}

  if "ERROR" in [message]  {
 email {
        from => "logstash.alert@nowhere.com"
        subject => "logstash alert"
        to => "test.lms@gmail.com"
        via => "smtp"
        body => "Here is the event line that occured: %{message}"
    }
 }
}
```

`
Here i am not not getting any email from that configuration.So anyone please find that configuration give the solution for me thanks...

Comment: I tested with the debug option, it's giving Email Output registered:{all config values coming}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes finally i got the solution for sending email alerts for any ERROR in message field.

```
output {

    elasticsearch {
            bind_host => "127.0.0.1"
            port => "9200"
            protocol => http
       }

    if  "ERROR" in [message]  {
    email  {
        options => [ "smtpIporHost", "smtp.gmail.com",
         "port", "587",
         "userName", "test@gmail.com",
         "password", "your password",
         "authenticationType", "plain",
         "starttls","true"
           ]
            from => "<test@gmail.com>"
            subject => "logstash alert"
            to => "<test@gmail.com>"
            via => "smtp"
            body => "Here is the event line that occured: %{message}"
       }
    }

    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting This error.

```
logstash_1       | [2017-08-14T07:05:57,056][ERROR][logstash.plugins.registry] Problems loading a plugin with {:type=>"output", :name=>"email", :path=>"logstash/outputs/email", :error_message=>"NameError", :error_class=>NameError, :error_backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/registry.rb:221:in `namespace_lookup'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/registry.rb:157:in `legacy_lookup'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/registry.rb:133:in `lookup'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/registry.rb:175:in `lookup_pipeline_plugin'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugin.rb:137:in `lookup'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:88:in `plugin'", "(eval):16:in `initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1079:in `eval'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:60:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:139:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:277:in `create_pipeline'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:95:in `register_pipeline'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:264:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:183:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:71:in `(root)'"]}
logstash_1       | [2017-08-14T07:05:57,108][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Cannot load an invalid configuration {:reason=>"Couldn't find any output plugin named 'email'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the email output plugin resulted in this error: Problems loading the requested plugin named email of type output. Error: NameError NameError"}
logstash_1       | 2017-08-14 07:05:57,210 Api Webserver ERROR No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

Please have a look and let me know if we have to do some extra configuration to use email.